# rcp / rsh missing in windows 7

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, rsh

I have existing batch scripts which work in windows xp. These scripts use rcp and rsh commands that are supported in windows xp .

These scripts are used to connect to a unix box and transfer files to it. Later using rsh, the files are installed on the system.

In Windows 7 these commands seems to be unavailable. I am stuck on how to make existing installation work on windows 7

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to this problem. The below steps needs to be followed:

1. Copy the following executable and dlls from windows xp machine to a folder (say c:\Windows\OldTools) on your windows 7 machine

   - advapi32.dll
   - kernel32.dll
   - msvcrt.dll
   - mswsock.dll
   - rcp.exe
   - rsh.exe
   - user32.dll
   - ws2_32.dll
2. Click on start menu -> right click on computer -> select Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables -> In "System Variables" section double click on "Path" -> Add the following text at the end 
   **;c:\Windows\OldTools**  
   The scripts now recognizes the rcp and rsh commands.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search will show you that both [RCP](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/tp/windows-7-commands-p2.05.htm) and [RSH](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/tp/windows-7-commands-p2.07.htm) are -

> "not available by default in Windows 7 but can be enabled by turning on the Subsystem for UNIX-based Applications Windows feature from Programs and Features in Control Panel and then installing the Utilities and SDK for UNIX-based Applications available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2391)."

Comment: I have tried this option,  but they are Unix based commands and are different in syntax and usage than the commands that were available with the Command prompt of the windows

Comment: Presumably though, they have the ability to do the same thing, even if the syntax is different. Take a look at the usage of those commands in Windows. Try `rcp /?` and `rsh /?`. If that doesn't give you help for those commands, just Google their Windows usage.

Comment: @SudhakarSingh Has this worked for you, if not, what is the problem?

Comment: This didn't work. I tried using the rcp with the new executable by copying it to the system32 folder. It gives unknown error while i try to transfer the file. The command is :
" rcp test.txt xx.xxx.xx.32.root:/tmp "
where xx.xxx.xx.32 is the IP of the remote unix system

Comment: What do you mean by "Unknown error", what does it say? You could try using `WinSCP` instead of `rcp`.

Comment: It gives me this error "ux:ksh: ERROR: rsh: not found" as internally it tries to use rsh

Comment: That's right, it's a [free client for windows](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php), with basically the same [command line extensible](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline) as `scp`. You just need to download it.

Comment: Two relevant data for anyone considering installing the subsystem: you need Win 7 Ultimate or Enterprise (https://superuser.com/questions/212864/sua-missing-from-windows-features?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)  (not Home, not Pro) and for Intel Core processors one has to nonintuitively [download the AMD64 version of the file](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/9d3da292-c1c6-4852-9342-35d232a5f1fb/cant-install-utilities-and-sdk-for-subsystem-for-unixbased-applications?forum=windowssdk).

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution on a Windows 10 machine. But when executing rcp.exe (or rsh.exe) I got the following error window:

"The procedure entry point DnsGetIpAddressList could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\test-rcp\MSWSOCK.DLL."

C:\test-rcp\ is the folder where I copied the .exe and the dll files.

I gave a try to delete the mswsock.dll. After doing that, running rcp (without parameters) showed the help (started to look good!) However, I executed a test to copy a local file to a remote server with a RSHD daemon running, and the file was not copied. rcp didn't throw any error message. The RSHD daemon is working fine when rcp'ing files from a server with old Windows version supporting rcp.